# Derivative of Yosida-Approximation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, approximation-theory, parabolic-pde

i have got a problem with some assumptions to solve a parabolic variational inequality. My Problem is: Find a function $u$ with

\begin{align}
u\in L^2(0,T;V),~ u' \in L^2(0,T;V') \\
(u'(t),v-u(t)) + a(u(t),v-u(t)) + \psi(v) -\psi(u(t)) \geq (f(t),v-u(t)) \\
u(0) = u_0.
\end{align}

We want to approximate $\psi$ with its Yosida-Approximation $\psi_j$ (it is convex and lower-semicontinuous.) Now the Duvaut & Lions postulate, that there is a bounded sequence $\lbrace \varphi_j\rbrace \subset V$, so that
\begin{align}
\psi_j'(\varphi_j) = 0 ~\forall j \in \mathbb{N}.
\end{align}

Is there any result, that proves this postulation? Thanks in advance, FFoDWindow

Comment: What is V? Banach/Hilbert space?

Comment: I assume you mean the Moreau envelope of $\psi$? (The Yosida approximation is the corresponding regularization of the subdifferential $\partial \psi$). In this case (assuming $\psi$ is bounded from below), $\psi_j$ admits a minimizer (in fact, the same as $\psi$) , which, since the Moreau envelope is differentiable (with derivative given by the Yosida approximation of the subdifferential), satisfies the necessary optimality condition $\psi_j'(\varphi_j)=0$.

Comment: @Christian Clason thank you for this precise answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one else has written an answer, I'm copying my comment:

If $\psi$ is convex and bounded from below (which I'm assuming since you didn't state anything), the Moreau envelope $\psi_j$ admits a minimizer (in fact, the same as $\psi$) for any $j$. Since the Moreau envelope is differentiable, this minimizer -- call it $\phi_j$ -- must satisfy the first-order necessary optimality condition $\psi_j'(\phi_j)=0$.

For the mentioned properties (and many, many more) of the Moreau envelope (and the Yosida approximation of subdifferentials), see Bauschke and Combette, *Convex Analysis and Monotone Operators in Hilbert Spaces*, Springer 2011.